# How do I move custom- commands into a separate file and include them in .spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, customize

I don't know whether it is because I started using org-mode but when I checked the `.spacemacs` file this is what I found:

```lisp
;; Do not write anything past this comment. This is where Emacs will       
;; auto-generate custom variable definitions.                              
(custom-set-variables                                                      
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.                              
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.           
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                  
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                      
 '(org-agenda-files (quote ("~/doc.org"))))
(custom-set-faces                                                          
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.                                  
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.           
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                  
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                      
 )
```

I don't know what `Custom` is but on further research I find out that I can create a separate file and configure .spacemacs to read from it. eg

```lisp
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/custom.el")
(load custom-file)
```

Where in `.spacemacs` should this part go? When copied into custom.el should they be copied directly as they are, ie into the top-level of the custom.el, or are they supposed to go into a function which will then be called from `.spacemacs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take the whole text of your first code snippet and stuff it into the `custom.el` file as it is.
After you have done this, put your second code snippet in place of the previously copied stuff (replacing the former copied text in file `.spacemacs`).

Thats it. Just try it. Emacs will complain if you did it wrong.

`Custom` is the customization function of emacs. You can change nearly every setting of emacs with it.
Call it with `Menu` -> `Options` -> `Customize Emacs` (and several other functions).

After you have done the modification, emacs will handle the custom.el file all by itself, no need to edit it directly.